# Augmented reality Interaction between two phones

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I try use Wikitude to development AR app. (Use Unity)
Now I want phones can interact with each other.

I think if at the same place I need GPS indoor, so it's seem difficult. I just want they can create group and play together.

If anyone have solution, thanks a lot

Comment: Since you're using Wikitude, you could just use the same marker that can be read by both phones. In other words, the marker could be used as a way to know both phones are at the same location and looking at the same thing.

Comment: I want ex:have 5 balloons object display on ceiling, someone bust one balloon. And all phones have 4.

Comment: The marker could mark the location/id of your game. Then you would need to maintain this id in an online database that all the other phones would be synchronized to. That would be one way of doing it.